# building a parser with clang

Tags: clang

I need to build an AST using clang and the only tutorials that I found are vague and two years out of date. Could anybody point me to an example?

Answer (score 15):

There are several tutorial available that demonstrate the use of the `Preprocessor` class and how to build an AST:

- [A CLang tutorial](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html) (a bit outdated but with a lot of explanation)
- [Code samples](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial)

Comment: +1 for the nice and useful link, but seems quite out of date. The code examples don't compile properly. Any useful link, which explains from the scratch how to get a source file and then analyze its source code and so on..?

Comment: It seems that things change pretty quickly in the clang world. I guess the up-to-date link is now http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. From that I found and going through [LibTooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html), which seems to be of my interest.

Comment: Thanks! Very few of links :)