# Parsing C++ to make some changes in the code

Tags: c++, parsing

I would like to write a small tool that takes a C++ program (a single .cpp file), finds the "main" function and adds 2 function calls to it, one in the beginning and one in the end.

How can this be done? Can I use g++'s parsing mechanism (or any other parser)?

Comment: How about this idea:  create a class that calls the appropriate functions in its constructor and destructor.  then stick in something like `namespace { MyClass myClassInstance; }` at the end of the file.  Will run before/after `main`.

Comment: @Lambdageek make it a answer...

Comment: @Lambdageek: That's a great idea! But it also makes me realize that the program I am testing may do the same. Do you know if it's possible to make sure the "myClassInstance" is the first object to be created and the last to be destroyed? Will this happen is "myClassInstance" is the first object declared?

Comment: @Lambdageek: Definitely make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by some commenters, let me put forward my idea as an answer:

So basically, the idea is:

```
... original .cpp file ...

#include <yourHeader>
namespace { 
  SpecialClass  specialClassInstance;
}
```

Where `SpecialClass` is something like:

```
class SpecialClass {
  public:
    SpecialClass() {
        firstFunction();
    }

    ~SpecialClass() {
        secondFunction();
    }
}
```

This way, you don't need to parse the C++ file.  Since you are declaring a global, its constructor will run before `main` starts and its destructor will run after `main` returns.

The downside is that you don't get to know the relative order of when your global is constructed compared to others.  So if you need to guarantee that `firstFunction` is called
before any other constructor elsewhere in the entire program, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make it solid, use [clang's libraries](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#applications).

Comment: That said, if it's just for some one-shot thing, it doesn't necessarily has to be "solid". You may well be all set by some perl or python script, like "@thomson_matt" mentioned (sadly, he erased his answer. I think it was a good one, if it would have included some sort of cautious words!).

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the GCC parser is both hard to use and even harder to get at without invoking the whole toolchain. I would try the clang C/C++ parser ([libparse](http://libparse)), and the tutorials linked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471633/building-a-parser-with-clang) question.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a function at the beginning of `main()` and at the end of `main()` is a bad idea. What if someone calls `return` in the middle?.
A better idea is to instantiate a class at the beginning of `main()` and let that class destructor do the call function you want called at the end. This would ensure that that function always get called.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of your main program, you can hack a script to do this, and that's by far the easiet way.  Simply make sure the insertion points are obvious (odd comments, required placement of tokens, you choose) and unique (including outlawing general coding practices if you have to, to ensure the uniqueness you need is real).  Then a dumb string hacking tool to read the source, find the unique markers, and insert your desired calls will work fine.

If the souce of the main program comes from others sources, and you don't have control, then to do this well you need a full C++ program transformation engine. You don't want to build this yourself, as just the C++ parser is an enormous effort to get right. Others here have mentioned Clang and GCC as answers.

An alternative is our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its C++ front end.  DMS, using its C++ front end, can parse code (for a variety of C++ dialects), builds ASTs, carry out full name/type resolution to determine the meaning/definition/use of all symbols.   It provides procedural and source-to-source transformations to enable changes to the AST, and can regenerate compilable source code complete with original comments.