# "simple" parser for c++

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, compiler-construction, sed

I have a project (SCC) which is kind of like REPL for C++.  At bush prompt I can do

```
scc '2+2'
```

Or little bit more complex:

```
scc  'double x = 0.5;  sin(x)'
```

which is equivalent to:

```
scc  'double x = 0.5;  cout << sin(x) << endl;'
```

If last (and possible only) statement-expression is not terminated by semicolon it is sent to `std::cout`.
My question is about parsing out last statment from C++ code snippet.
I am well aware how difficult C++ parsing is.  Parsing out last statement with simple sed script by just looking for last `';'` was initially good enough for me.
But now project is bigger than small personal project and I need a better parser.

Below is mini unit-test for my current SED parser. You can see SED regex which I use to do the parsing:

```
    cat  <<EOF  | sed    's/$//;s/[ \t]*$//;s/\(.*[;}]\)*\([^;}]\+$\)/\0    ==>>  \1   PRINT(\2);/'


    print
    no-print;
    OK;  print
    OK;  no-print;
    OK;  no-print;  print
    FAIL;   while(a){b;}  no-print
    FAIL;   while(a)  no-print
    OK;     for(a;b;c) {no-print}
    FAIL;   for(a;b;c) no-print
    OK;     {}
    OK;     {no-print-code-block;}
    FAIL;  print_rvalue_t{1}
    FAIL;   f(int{1})
    FAIL;   f(";")
    FAIL;   f(';')
    FAIL;   f("}")
    EOF
```

First line after `cat`-line is empty line.  Second line is one space  line.
3rd - statment not terminated with `';'` - should be printed.  4th - 2-statment
snippet. And so on.  If there is `FAIL` - parser will fail at this line. Output
looks like this:

```
    print   ==>>     PRINT(print);
    no-print;
    OK;  print      ==>>  OK;   PRINT(  print);
    OK;  no-print;
    OK;  no-print;  print   ==>>  OK;  no-print;   PRINT(  print);
    FAIL;     while(a){b;}  print     ==>>  OK;       while(a){b;}   PRINT(  no-print);
    FAIL;   while(a)  no-print      ==>>  FAIL;   PRINT(    while(a)  no-print);
    OK;     for(a;b;c) {no-print}
    FAIL;   for(a;b;c) no-print     ==>>  FAIL;     for(a;b;   PRINT(c) no-print);
    OK;     {}
    OK;     {no-print-code-block;}
    FAIL;  print_rvalue_t{1}
    FAIL;   f(int{1})       ==>>  FAIL;     f(int{1}   PRINT());
    FAIL;   f(";")  ==>>  FAIL;     f(";   PRINT("));
    FAIL;   f(';')  ==>>  FAIL;     f(';   PRINT('));
    FAIL;   f("}")  ==>>  FAIL;     f("}   PRINT("));
```

Lines without `==>>` marker are lines that are passed through parser without modifications.  After marker is transformed snippet, where last statement is wrapped in `PRINT( )`.
As you can see current SED parser is not very good.

So am looking for something better.  I will accept the answer even if it is not
100% correct at parsing.  Even better SED script would be good enough for me.
Right way to do it would be probably to use real parser (from something like
CLANG) but I am a little bit apprehensive of  complexity of this endeavor.

I've tried to write a parser in boost/xpressive -  http://github.com/lvv/scc/blob/master/sccpp.h . Of cause it's not real C++
parser. It's just a quick hack made just for one thing: parse out last statement.  It is
able to do all above unit tests.  But unfortunately, for longer snippets it was
intolerably slow.

Question is: how to make a better parser?

Comment: You should probably learn to use tools like [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) and [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc). Sed will never be good enough to parse a real language, not even a subset of a language. And if you want to parse the whole of C++, then you can't make a "simple" parser, as C++ is incredibly complex.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend starting from scratch and writing a C++ parser using flex and bison, instead you can get something really good if you invest time in developing something based on clang parser API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471633/building-a-parser-with-clang

Comment: There already is a clang-based C++ REPL in development (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling). Development is seems to progress fast, and they anticipate to to a production release in November 2012. There are a few impressive demonstrations on youtube.

Comment: @honk - yes, thanks.  I know about this.  SCC is very different from CLING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right way to do it would be probably to use real parser (from
>   something like CLANG) but I am a little bit apprehensive of complexity
>   of this endeavor

Not *too* high. The simple fact is that C++ is like HTML- you need a real library to do it, so unless you want to spend years developing your own, pretty much the only way to go is to use an existing C++ parser. Clang is the only option in this regard. So however complex you find it, you have no other choice.

Comment: “C++ is like HTML” – it’s as if millions of geeks cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.

Comment: In this exact comparative respect, I believe that it is.

Comment: Clang is not the only option. Elsa is pretty usable, although a bit outdated.

Comment: @DeadMG Sure, and I upvoted. The juxtaposition just sounds funny.