# Open source ANSI C99 parser?

Tags: c, parsing

I'm interested in playing around with adding some language features on top of C and I'm trying to find a good open source parser that I could fork to play with making grammar changes, but I'm not having any lucky just yet.  Does anyone know of a good "standalone" parser that would be amenable to modification in this way?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471633/building-a-parser-with-clang

Comment: I definitely thought of Clang, but I'm turned off by it's unified parser that includes C++, objective-c and such.  If I'm ever successful and want to release my new language, that's a lot of extra code to carry around...

Comment: What's wrong with GCC?  And what will you do with *just* a parser?

Comment: Haha, yes, unfortunately that is the case. However I have the expierience that LLVM, the base for Clang, has some pretty expansive AST libraries, so I suppose you could somewhat easily separate ANSI C and C++ etc.

Comment: @IraBaxter He intends to create a modified language

Comment: @Ira Nothing at all, the only reason I'm not considering it as a first option is that it's GPL.  I'd prefer a more permissive license because I like to release my stuff as BSD/MIT, though in this instance maybe that won't matter.  I plan to write my own back-end to round-trip the parsed AST back to ANSI C, then I can play around with adding language features with C an as intermediate output.

Comment: [Grr.  Why do people say "open source" when they mean a specific license?]  If you add a feature that changes the machine context (e.g., local functions with goto to outer functions), or uses properties not available in native C (e.g., parallelism), you may not be able to express the effect in your target language C.

Comment: ... A parser won't cut it.  You need full name and type resolution if you intend to add langauge features which have any context sensitivity, or you won't be able to validate them.

Comment: @Sorry IS holud have been more specific in my license preferences.  I know there's definitely stuff I might not be able to express in C, but a lot of what I want to do is compile-time desugaring for things like generics, multiple return values, built-in syntax for lists/dictionariess, etc.    I know there's more to it than just the parsing, but I see that as the big part, name and type resolution isn't monstrously difficult after that I don't think.

Comment: @gct: A lesson: parsing C++ is widely known to be a bitch.  It isn't anything as hard as name and type resolution.  C99 is likely to be easier, but don't assume it is easy just because you haven't done it before.

Comment: You might want to submit this question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing it in Python, you can use [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser). It's a fully compliant C99 parser licensed under the 3-clause BSD license.

Comment: I came across that!  It sounds so good but I'm not sure I can assume I have python available all the time =(

Comment: @gct: What do you mean? CPython is pretty portable. They even have an Android version! Plus, you can embed it in a C program.

Comment: I took a little closer look and it looks like they just use Lexx/Yacc to generate their python code, so it might not be the easiest to modify as well.

Comment: @gct: Not really. PLY(what it uses) is a library that behaves similarly to Lex/Yacc. There is a set of extensions to pycparser called [pycparserext](https://github.com/inducer/pycparserext) that adds support for GNU extensions. It's a great example of extending pycparser.

Comment: Taking a look now, maybe this will work for what I want to do.